# UIScrollView with controls repeating on every page?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, paging, uipagecontrol

I have perfectly working UIPageControl. I would like to add paging by swipe, and as I understood, it is done by UIScrollView.
But all tutorials are done with images, I want to have controls (labels, buttons) repeating on every page.

Because UIScrollControl is working the way that it must have set its width * pages count, does it mean, that controls can be placed only in code, not in IB?

Should I place labels and buttons directly on UIScrollView?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I would do that programmatically. However, what do you mean by "repeating on every page"? Do you want to have the same/identical controls on every page? (If so, why? :-) And do you want to be able to scroll or page "endless"?

Comment: Yes, I want two labels on every page, but each time with different text. And yes, I want to have "endless" paging. Why, is it somehow important, if endless, or not?

Comment: How do you want to display endless scrolling with a UIPageControl? However, I would create a UIScrollView of the size of 3 screens with paging enabled. When ever the slide is scrolled to the right or left I would re-adjust it so that its middle part is visible again and move/re-arrange (or in your case rename) all the Items on that scroll view so that the user does not notice the change. By doing so you can achieve endless scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a View Controller designed using IB with all its buttons and labels, then it is possible to add that View Controller as a subview of your UIScrollView as such:

`[scrollView addSubview:controller.view];`

scrollView being your UIScrollView and controller being your IB designed View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve repeating controls with pagecontroll by using IB by ordering the objects appropriately. Here's what I have:

Drag the UIScrollview to the ViewController and also the drag the Page Controller and other controls also to the ViewController but not onto the UIScrollView. Keep them separate. The objects on the bottom of the IB list of objects shows up at the top of the view stack. (So when you swipe new pages the controls dont move and isn't covered by the UIScrollView) I also group the various controls by group selecting them and then use the "embed with view" menu item so that in IB I have two groups, the controls and the UIScrollView. Makes it neater and easier to manage. As for changing labels, I haven't tried it but I've seen tutorials where you can have iboutlets linked to changing value of pagecontroller and then update the labels in uiscrollview appropriately.